# Cannot add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions to project template created with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Trying to create a new project in Visual Studio 2019 using ASP.NET core + React + Redux template

I am new to VS2019 + ASP.NET, just trying to get a basic template going, but IDE is showing this under error list:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages   <projectName> <projectPath> 1
```

.csproj shows this dependency:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.14" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I tried installing the dependency using the command line, as described on https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/3.1.14

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions --version 3.1.14
```

But now I get this error:

```
error: Package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project
```

It seems awfully strange to me that the IDE's template doesn't work out of the box, nor can I install what appears to be the dependency required for the template.  Has anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with VS2019 and .Net5, the solution I found is this, go to

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings

then select Package Sources and click on the option to add a new source, use this url for the source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

you can find more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources